# Empty dialogfragment in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, android-dialogfragment, layout-inflater

I am trying to pop a dialog fragment on the loginscreenactivity onclick a button which has the register form.

I am pretty sure that the dialog is opening but i am not able to inflate it properly.

when a button is clicked for the `DialogFragment` something appears but it is blank completely, wherein I am expecting a layout that I have created for register form.

I've read the code keenly, I don't seem to find the problem.

Here is my `DialogFragment`

```
class dialog_fragment:DialogFragment
{
    private Button btn;
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Register, container, false);

        btn = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnRegister);
        btn.Click += delegate 
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "something", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        };
        return view;
    }
}
```

This I include where I am showing the dialog

```
        btnRegister.Click += delegate
        {
            FragmentTransaction ft = FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            dialog_fragment signup = new dialog_fragment();
            signup.Show(ft,"dialog signup");
        };
```

the solution might be very dumb, thanks in advance

Comment: where are you showing the dialogfragment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vaibhav, as you were expecting, the solution is dumb but this happens.

you have dialog fragment that is supposed to return a dialog, but sadly there are two returns in the dialogfragment class.

your solution here.

no wonder it will not return anything  on `base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);`

you don't ever meet line `var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Register, container, false);`

remove the return before `base.OnCreateView()`

```
class dialog_fragment:DialogFragment
{
private Button btn;
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //return
    base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Register, container, false);

    btn = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnRegister);
    btn.Click += delegate 
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this.Activity, "something", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    };
    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: thanks Akshay I tend to skip the keywords like return this was silly. thanks for noticing this one here.